# Amide from acyl azide

Tags: organic-chemistry, redox, carbonyl-compounds

There are several reports of synthesis of amines from acyl azides via Staudinger reaction with triphenylphosphine.

Are there any reports of Staudinger reactions of acyl azides to amides? If not, are there any reports on reduction of acyl azides to amides? I have found a paper (http://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1081/SCC-120014032) that talks about the reduction of acyl azides to amides using zinc and ammonium chloride, but I am looking for some other reactions as well.